# SSIS: Import Excel file to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a Excel version for this article? I have been searching for this past days but there is no luck.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Comment: Will you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: [ExcelFilePath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21536893/181965)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple Excel file load, you can just use the Import Wizard to create an SSIS package for you (available by right clicking the Database, and selecting Tasks -> Import Data) and even save that package for future use.

If this is a process where you need to take data from an Excel file, transform it, then load it, then yes a custom SSIS package will work better.  You should be able to add a new connection and indicate that it is an excel file using the "new Connection Manager" wizard in your SSIS package.